# Property or indexer 'System.Nullable.Value' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, nullable

I'm developing an winform app. Based of some values (say x) I want to show user an alert, a timer updated other value (y), which affect x, and check for value of x and show alert to user. 
Alert show a message box with yes/no options, if user click yes then some processing.

If user did not respond to alert for a long time (say 10 min), there can multiple alert messages show, I want to prevent that I created a nullable DialogResult variable, so I can check if user has selected any option or not. Now the problem is that it does not allow to set me the value of that variable

```
taskAlert.Value=MessageBox.Show(kMessage, appErrorTitle, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
```

I gives me error -Property or indexer 'System.Nullable.Value' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The problem is that you're trying to assign directly to the `Value` property.** The `Value` property is marked as read-only, which is why the compiler is showing you that error.

Instead, you should assign a value to a variable of type [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) the exact same way that you would any other type. For example, the above code would simply become:

```
taskAlert = MessageBox.Show(kMessage, appErrorTitle, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
```

The only thing that changes is *accessing* the value. You first need to check the [`HasValue` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx), and if it return True, then you'll retrieve the value using the [`Value` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx). If the `HasValue` property returns False, then the value of the object is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, you don't need a nullable value here.

The [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) enumeration has a value "None", which can be used to indicate that the user has not selected an option.